# What's the correct way to authorize PhoneGap application to the Facebook?

Tags: facebook, cordova, oauth, facebook-javascript-sdk

I spent a while already to fix annoying issue with Facebook in PhoneGap app. And still a lot of things goes wrong with that. The thing is that I use Appery.io and Facebook plugin.

This is how my Facebook console looks now:

[image]

I suggest that localhost might be a reason of the issue. However, I got it into Facebook_Helper.js:

[image]

Everytime I try to sign in with FB account, I get the same error at the child window:

[image]

So what I've got is that app is authorized at this moment indeed, because there's a menu button at the navbar that allows me to navigate through FB profile:

[image]

The first issue lies in that the child window never gets closed automatically once user submitted Sign In form.  And the second one is that I can't get the access token to the app directly. I know I'm doing something wrong, but I spend more than a week on that and nothing was clarified.

Honestly, I've no idea why it's not working. I saw a lot of apps written in PhoneGap that use the same authorization too, and they work as it should. Will be appreciate if you take a look into that and, maybe, advice something.

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't see iOS or Android in your developer.facebook screenshot.

Second, you should implement native facebook integration if you are developing an app, if I understand correctly from your code, you are trying to handle only web browser version of authentication. Native integration is both the suggested way by facebook and platforms and better experience for end users. If users have facebook app installed, authenticating over fb app is more secure after all..

You can use a cordova plugin for facebook integration, here is one of the plugins (I am one of the authors): [cordova-facebook plugin](https://github.com/ccsoft/cordova-facebook)